# Angular 7 - add image tag with attributes to an editable div at cursor

Tags: angular

I'm a so-so newbie in Angular 7 and want to basically insert an Image (or different images) with a (click) event in a editable div. Basically want to mimick a WYSIWYG editor and place it where the cursor caret is.

Can someone help me figure out how to do this in Angular 7.

Haven't figured out how exactly to play around with the DOM in Angular 7 yet.

Any pointers much appreciated!

```
<div contenteditable="true" id="editor">Please type something in here
</div>
<button (click)="insertImage1()">Image 1</button>
<button (click)="insertImage2()">Image 2</button>
```

So after I click say the Image 1 button and cursor caret at after the word 'type', it will become like this.

```
<div contenteditable="true" id="editor">Please type <img src="someimage.gif">something in here
</div>
<button (click)="insertImage1()">Image 1</button>
<button (click)="insertImage2()">Image 2</button>
```

Comment: share your ts code

Comment: Haven't added anything in the TS. I'm stuck with finding out the cursor position of the editable Div.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `insertHTML` command like this

```
const img = '<img src="someimage.gif">';

document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, img);
```

[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2bkpww?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: I'm looking to find out the cursor position then insert the image there. Any idea how I can do that in Angular?